# In MySQL, will changing the schema of a primary key affect the schema of foreign keys in other tables?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, schema, constraints

We are in the midst of trying to clean up the database and debating about whether or not to put in place foreign key constraints on our tables.  It would be a very convincing argument for using them if changing the schema of a primary key in one table affected the schema of foreign keys in other tables.  But is this the case?

For example, let's say I have a USER table with primary key **id** and I have another table BLOGGERS whose **blogger_id** is a foreign key tied to **id**.  Let's say that **id** is initially declared as a SMALLINT, but then I have hordes of users signing up and we need to increase the range available for ids.  If I alter **id** to be and INT, will that automatically alter **blogger_id** in the BLOGGER table to be an INT also?

Regardless of the answer to my primary question, does anyone know of any compelling reasons to formally declare foreign key constraints, other than to limit the data the can be placed in that field?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, MySQL does not change the data type in child tables if you change the data type in the parent table.

I had to help one of my consulting customers who had reached the maximum INT value in their `Users` table. But as you can imagine, there were 30 other tables that referenced `Users`. We had to `ALTER TABLE` on each of those other 30 tables before we could change the primary key data type in the `Users` table, because it wouldn't work if new user id's could not be referenced by the child tables.

As for your question about foreign keys, yes, I do recommend them for the sake of enforcing data integrity. In every database I have analyzed that tried to do without foreign keys, they had a lot of orphaned rows in child tables, with no automatic way of detecting them.

That said, it's surprisingly common for sites to forego foreign keys, assuming they will "just do the right thing" in their application code to avoid orphaned data.

One of the arguments against foreign keys is that the presence of foreign keys creates some cases of locking that you may not expect. If I UPDATE a child row, you expect it to lock that row for the duration of your transaction. But if you have a foreign key, this *also* locks the parent row, in the table referenced by the foreign key.

Example: suppose you have a parent table `ShoppingCart` and a child table `LineItems`. If you UPDATE the quantity of a row in `LineItems`, your transaction makes an exclusive lock (X-lock) on that row. But it also makes a shared lock (S-lock) on the parent row in `ShoppingCart`. It makes sense that you wouldn't want the row you're depending on to be DELETEd, for example, while you're in progress of working on one of the rows that references it.

This is a *shared lock*, so multiple transactions can have this kind of lock at the same time, but then if you need to update the parent row directly while one or more clients have those implicit shared locks, you are blocked.

Comment: That's what I needed to know.  Gracias!